# How do you mock an object instantiated inside another object in Groovy?

Tags: testing, groovy

Here's my example code

```
class CommandLine {

    def ls() {
        def cmd = "ls".execute()
        if(cmd.waitFor() != 0) {
            throw new Execution()
        }
        return cmd.text
    }
}
```

The `cmd` variable holds an object of type java.lang.Process.  How would I mock out the `waitFor()` method in order to test the thrown exception?  If I can't, is there some way this could be rewritten to facilitate automated testing?

In general, how do you mock an object instantiated inside another class, or how do you structure your code to allow for testing?

Comment: Well, common technique is to mockup the `execute` function to return the mocked up `java.lang.Process` instead of the regular one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use Groovy mocks instead of the built in Grails mocks.

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor

class TestClass {

    def test() {
        def mock = new MockFor(classToBeMocked)

        mock.demand.methodToBeMocked(1..1) { -> /* code */ }

        mock.use {
            /*
            All calls to objects of type classToBeMocked will be 
            intercepted within this block of code.
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Groovy, but if there's a chance of mocking the method `String#execute()` to return a mocked `Process` with a method `waitFor()` which returns not zero result it would be the way to do it

Something like:

```
Process mockedProcess = MockingFramework.mock(Process.class); // MockingFramework can be Mockito
MockingFramework.when(String.execute()).thenReturn(mockedProcess);
MockingFramework.when(mockedProcess.waitFor).thenReturn(1);

new CommandLine().ls(); // Boom! => Execution exception
```